# javascript memory leak with requre js and js anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, memory-management, require

After executing below lines of code, the `User` object was not being collected by GC. It is was showing on chrome heap snapshot.

Can anyone help?

```
 define("mockModule", [], function () {
 function User(name) {
    var that = this;
    this.name = name;
    this.column = [{ id: 'xyz' }];
    this.createObj();
}
User.prototype.createObj = function () {
    var that = this;
    this.column[0]['formatter'] = outerFunction(that);
};
 User.prototype.dummyMethod = function () {
 } ;
 function outerFunction(that) {
    return function () {
        return that.dummyMethod(that)
    };
  }
 return { User: User };
});

    define("mockModuleImpl", ["mockModule"], function (mockModule) {
 function init() {
    var user = new mockModule.User("hello");
    user = null;
 }
 return { init: init }; 
});

  require(["mockModuleImpl"], function (mockModuleImpl) {
      mockModuleImpl.init();
});
```

Comment: So what is that object's retaining tree?

Comment: not all unreferenced objects are claimed immediately.read this http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page424.html and this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management